# errors connecting to sonarqube server built in Azure, unverified host and unable to find certificate path

Tags: java, azure, ssl, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have set up sonarqube server on a VM in Azure with Azure sql. A self signed cert was created using IIS.

I can connect to the server via a remote browser and after installing the certificate into the Trusted CA I can successfully connect to the server with no warnings.

However on running the sonar-scanner.bat from a a  remote client,  I receive the following error :

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I followed some guidelines to install the certificate into the Java keystore by exporting the certificate via IE then importing it into the JAVA  keychain as below
keytool -importcert -file c:\sonarcertnew.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Aliasonar but this then gives another error : Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname  not verified:

So despite exporting the cert and importing into the java keystore still unable to connect. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late to help you with this but just solved this issue myself and though I'd add my solution to this for future Googlers!

My problem was caused by trying to use the IP address that Azure assigned to the server, I couldn't get the certificate to work with Java. In the end, I gave my Azure VM a DNS and re-exported the certificate and imported to both Windows and Java. This solved the SSLHandshakeException for me.